# Importing lettable RxJS operators

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

RxJS 5.5 makes a big breaking change and introduces [lettable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md) to replace basically all operators (called "patch" operators) we used to use before.

That article contains a note:

> Lettable operators can now be imported from rxjs/operators, but doing
>   so without changing your build process will often result in a larger
>   application bundle. This is because by default rxjs/operators will
>   resolve to the CommonJS output of rxjs.

This statement is easy to proof on the practice with the brand new AngularCLI-generated app.

When we have an application that doesn't import anything from RxJS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public title = 'app';

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
}
```

We can see the following:

```
ng build --prod
chunk {0} polyfills.e1f97a0070e18e96a6be.bundle.js (polyfills) 61.4 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.b2b5d212102ca9d103e8.bundle.js (main) 4.92 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css (styles) 0 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} vendor.4b7be3dbe842aec3f0ab.bundle.js (vendor) 236 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} inline.387c7023e5627ac04221.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

When we import a RxJS operator the "old" way and use it:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public title = 'app';

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
      .map((u: any) => 1)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
}
```

We can see no gain in size of bundles:

```
chunk {0} polyfills.e1f97a0070e18e96a6be.bundle.js (polyfills) 61.4 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.229ad10195bbb426b3e8.bundle.js (main) 4.96 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css (styles) 0 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} vendor.933334fc50e7008778fe.bundle.js (vendor) 236 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} inline.6a52179d8b19cd3cc179.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

When we try to import and use the lettable operator instead as recommended but without modifying the build process:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public title = 'app';

  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users').pipe(
        map((u: any) => 1))
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
}
```

We see that the vendor bundle is 108 kB bigger which tells us that RxJS hasn't been tree-shaked:

```
chunk {0} polyfills.e1f97a0070e18e96a6be.bundle.js (polyfills) 61.4 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.450c741a106157402dcd.bundle.js (main) 4.97 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css (styles) 0 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} vendor.3f53f0e2283f4c44ec38.bundle.js (vendor) 344 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} inline.2d973ef5a10aa806b082.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

When I try to import the lettable operator as recommended in the `No Control over Build Process` section of the article:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators/map";
```

I'm getting a build error:

```
./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operators/map' in 'c:\Projects\Angular\src\app'
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 14:0-41
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

1. What I'm doing wrong?
2. How can we import new RxJS lettable operators in an Angular CLI app
   so that RxJS would still be tree-shaked?

**UPDATE:** Package versions (basically all are latest "wanted" versions of an AngularCLI app at the moment):

```
rxjs: 5.5.0
@angular/cli: 1.4.9
node: 8.6.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.6
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Comment: It might quite be surprising, see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2867

Comment: @kemsky: Thank you for the info! The reason why it's not tree-shaked is explained in the article I provided. The question is basically how to workaround it with the current AngularCLI build system?

Comment: Could you please post `ng version` output. I found no build error with @angular/cli: 1.2.0, @angular/___: 4.4.6, rxjs@5.5.0-beta.7.

Comment: @RichardMatsen: Sure, I've updated my question. I'd very appreciate you, if you could try it with `rxjs: 5.5.0` (not `beta`) and `@angular/cli: 1.4.9`.

Comment: I updated to @angular/cli: 1.4.9 and the problem appears.

Comment: This works `import { map } from '../../node_modules/rxjs/operators/map'`

Comment: @RichardMatsen: Thank you for your input! It seems like a bug in `angular-cli 1.4.9`. I've tried with `angular-cli 1.4.8` and deep imports work!

Comment: There is now a GitHub issue for this problem: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, @angular/cli@1.4.9 adds the following in **models/webpack-configs/common.js**

```
// Read the tsconfig to determine if we should prefer ES2015 modules.
// Load rxjs path aliases.
// https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking
let alias = {};
try {
    const rxjsPathMappingImport = 'rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping';
    const rxPaths = require_project_module_1.requireProjectModule(projectRoot, rxjsPathMappingImport);
    alias = rxPaths(nodeModules);
}
catch (e) { }

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: ['node_modules', nodeModules],
        symlinks: !buildOptions.preserveSymlinks,
        alias
    },
```

and **rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping.js** has these two entries

```
"rxjs/operators": path.resolve(PATH_REPLACEMENT, "rxjs/_esm5/operators/index.js"),
...
"rxjs/operators/map": path.resolve(PATH_REPLACEMENT, "rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js"),
```

The essential bit of the error message is

```
aliased with mapping 'rxjs/operators': 
  'C:\Dev\Projects\rx55\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\operators\index.js' to 
  'C:\Dev\Projects\rx55\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\operators\index.js/map'
...
C:\Dev\Projects\rx55\node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\operators\index.js\map doesn't exist
```

so the first mapping is interfering with the second.

By reversing the order of the mappings the build works, so to my mind the fault is with rxjs v5.5.

That said, Alexander's work-around is the path to take until the fix.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you're really using at least `5.5.0`. Otherwise check that file `node_modules/rxjs/operators/map.js` exists because I don't know how could it not. Also using `import { map } from "rxjs/operators";` imports the same file underneath so I'd suspicious there's something wrong with your build system.
2. The correct way to use operators is to import them form `rxjs/operators/*` (for example like you did with `import { map } from "rxjs/operators/map";`).

   If you import from `rxjs/operators` it's the same like importing from `rxjs` in RxJS < 5.5.0 because you're in fact importing `rxjs/operators/index`, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operators/index.ts.

   That's why it didn't get "tree-shaken", it imported all operators listed in `index.ts`.

Comment: I checked my RxJS version, it's 5.5.0. The file indeed exists. In my question, I tested it on the brand new AngularCLI-generated app - you can easily check it yourself. It's not a build system issue. That article demonstrates that making a deep imports like `import { map } from "rxjs/operators/map";`is an alternative way to import in case you can't modify your build process to add the `ModuleConcatenationPlugin` plugin in order to tree-shake lettable operators. I'm not sure why it can't find something using deep imports. Maybe it's something related to AngularCLI build settings?

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out (credits to **@RichardMatsen**), it's a bug in `angular-cli 1.4.9`.

Trying deep imports (like `import { map } from "rxjs/operators/map";`) with `angular-cli 1.4.8`, there is no build errors and bundle sizes are:

```
chunk {0} polyfills.e1f97a0070e18e96a6be.bundle.js (polyfills) 61.4 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.d36cf6834f640163ff35.bundle.js (main) 4.97 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css (styles) 0 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} vendor.658e9efd9845db281b29.bundle.js (vendor) 241 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} inline.c9d245ca6c859aaeef69.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

Which shows only 5 kB gain compared to the version that doesn't use RxJS operators at all.

So for now, we have at least a workaround: stay on `angular-cli 1.4.8` and import lettable operatirs with deep imports like:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators/map";
import { filter } from "rxjs/operators/filter";
```