# Angular CLI - RXJS warning with PartialObserver

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

I am using Angular CLI (1.4.9 ), Angular 4.4.6 and RxJS (5.4.2) ...

When I serve my app via "ng serve" I get a WARNING:

> WARNING export 'PartialObserver' was not found in 'rxjs/Observer'
>       at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:65:15)
>       at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getWarnings (\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:39:15)
>       at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:701:24)
>       at Compilation.finish (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:559:9)
>       at applyPluginsParallel.err (\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:506:17)
>       at \node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:289:11
>       at _addModuleChain (\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:505:11)
>       at processModuleDependencies.err (\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:475:14)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

the sourcecode file generating the warning simply has:

```
import { PartialObserver } from 'rxjs/Observer';
```

which seems to run fine.  The Webpack bundling process completes successfully other than the warning.  I am getting no linter errors from the file.

Anyone have a clue what is causing this warning?  Is this an issue where the RxJS structure doesn't play nice with webpack somehow?

Comment: There's a problem with @angular/cli@1.4.9 and rxjs (5.5.0) which _might_ be related. Ref [Importing lettable RxJS operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853898/importing-lettable-rxjs-operators). Try installing @angular/cli@1.4.8.

Comment: Hmmm... rolling back to 1.4.8 did in fact get rid of the warnings.   I'm not using RxJS 5.5.. but maybe something in the CLI code changed in preparation for 5.5 and caused this quirk with < 5.5??  Thanks for the comment!